# How to validate that server certificate is revoked from client using openssl

Tags: c, openssl, client-certificates, ocsp

I am looking for ways to check if server certificate is revoked or not from C code in the client. Its a test server and for one test case, Server document mentions that "server certificate is revoked as indicated in the OCSP stapled reponse". When i see the certificate, it just has OCSP server URL. How to validate this from client side using openssl?

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960